# Counter goes down by 4 at the time instead of one (C#)

Tags: c#

I am new at C# and after learning the basics I've decided that I wanna make a Hangman game. The problem is that a counter that normally counts down from 8 by 1 each time I miss a letter is counting down by 4 and I have no idea why.

```
 static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int Chances= 8;
        bool key = false;
        int N= 10;
        char[] Word = { 'P', 'R', 'O', 'G', 'R', 'A', 'M' };
        Console.WriteLine("The word is:_ _ _ _ _ _ _");
        Console.Write("Please input a letter:");
        while (key == false)
        {
            char letter = Convert.ToChar(Console.Read());
            N = Numberofletter(letter);
            Console.WriteLine(N);
            while (N == 0 && Chances > 0)
            {
                Chances--;
                Console.WriteLine("The letter is incorrect you have " + K + " tries Remaining");
                letter = Convert.ToChar(Console.Read());



            };
            if (Chances == 0)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Gameover");
                return;

            }
static int Numberofletter(char letter)
    {
        int N = 0;
        char[] Word = { 'P', 'R', 'O', 'G', 'R', 'A', 'M' };
        if (Word[0] == letter)
        { N = 1; }
        else if (Word[1] == letter)
        { N = 2; }
        else if (Word[2] == letter)
        { N = 3; }
        else if (Word[3] == letter)
        { N = 4; }
        else if (Word[5] == letter)
        { N = 6; }
        else if (Word[6] == letter)
        { N = 7; }
        else { N = 0; }
        return N;
    }
```

Comment: What is `Numberofletter()`?

Comment: Numberofletter i am using as a method to make to transfer the user input into number

Comment: sorry for my random comments and things I am extremely new at this....

Comment: What are N and K?  Can you rename them to make the code more readable?

Comment: N is just a variable for me to keep track of which letter the user inputs and to check using my method named Numberofletters if the letter Is or is not In my Keyword "PROGRAM"

Comment: Please learn to use the debugger and step through the code, investigating the variables, as it stands this is a debugging problem

Comment: Thanks for the advice I will look into it.

Comment: @Edi - You might find this method useful: `"PROGRAM".IndexOf('R')`. In your case `Numberofletter` can be replaced by `"PROGRAM".IndexOf(letter) + 1`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in your while loop.

You enter the loop with N = position of the guessed letter = 0.
INSIDE the loop, you ask for another letter, but NEVER calculate its position.
So even if the letter is in the word, you've never re-assigned the value of N.  This means the loop will keep running and decrementing `chances` until `chances < 0;`

Simply add

```
N = Numberofletter(letter);
```

after you read in the next letter.

Comment: Thanks a lot, it would have taken me a lot more time to figure this out

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if anyone else will have the same problem as me but I will post my mistake here so at least I hope it will not be repeated

instead of `letter=Convert.ToChar(Console.Read());` 
you should use `letter=Convert.ToChar(Console.ReadLine());`
i don't know why was that the problem but it happend try it out randomly and it worked